# C to Java Conversion

Tags: java, c

I know someone will give me a hard time for this, but here goes.  I am trying to convert some C code to Java and am still learning java as I go.  I am having a very difficult time figuring out how to do this conversion and learning java for that matter.  Any help or pointers on where to go would be greatly appreciated.

```
for(d=alldevs; d; d=d->next)
    {
        printf("%d. %s", ++i, d->name);
        if (d->description)
            printf(" (%s)\n", d->description);
        else
            printf(" (No description available)\n");
    }

    if(i==0)
    {
        printf("\nNo interfaces found! Make sure WinPcap is installed.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Enter the interface number (1-%d):",i);
    scanf("%d", &inum);

    if(inum < 1 || inum > i)
    {
        printf("\nInterface number out of range.\n");
        /* Free the device list */
        pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Jump to the selected adapter */
    for(d=alldevs, i=0; i< inum-1 ;d=d->next, i++);
```

Comment: Which part, **specifically**, are you having trouble with?  No-one is going to just give you the translated code...

Comment: Pointer #1. Learn C, if you already do, go to pointer #2. Pointer #2. Learn Java, if you already do, go to pointer #3. Pointer #3. Convert you code, Voila!

Comment: What part of Im learning Java and having a difficult time with it.  I am not a programmer and am completely self taught.  I am here for some help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I find it odd that you are having trouble going from `C` to `Java`. Do you actually know C? Because if you do I am sure you can convert this code to Java based on the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) alone in no time. Example: Instead of `printf` look up the documentation for `System.out.println`

Comment: @pgfdbug We still won't do the work for you. This is not some FREE freelance work web site.

Comment: If we give you the translated code you learn nothing. We can help with specific problems you are having.

Comment: You might want to try to get a copy of Head First Java as it is a tutorial for learning Java that does not assume a large background of programming.

Comment: Thank you Kathy I will find it.  Marcelo I am nothing more than a beginner I am not making any money off the program just some help or pointers is what I am looking for sorry if my asking for help has offended you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conversion offering:

```
public class Item {

   private String name;

   private String description;

   public Item(String name, String description) {
     this.name = name;
     this.description = description;
   }

   public String getName() {
     return this.name;
   }

   public String getDescription() {
     return this.description;
   }

}

 (defined elsewhere)
 List<Item> items;
```

And now the code

```
int index = 1;
for (Item item: items) {
   System.out.print(index + ". " + item.getName());
   if (item.getDescription() != null) {
     System.out.println(" (" + item.getDescription() + ")");
   } else {
     System.out.println"( (No Description Available)");
   }
   index++;
}    

List<NetworkInterface> nets = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
if (nets.size() == 0) {
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("No interfaces found! Make sure WinPcap is installed.");
  return;
}

System.out.print("Enter the interface number(1-" + nets.size() + "):");
Byte[] input = new byte[100];
System.in.read(input);
String inString = new String(input);
int interfaceIndex = Integer.getInteger(inString);

if (interfaceIndex < 1 || interfaceindex > nets.size()) {
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Interface number out of range.");
   // freeing items is done by dereferencing
   nets = null;
   return;
} 

// jump to the selected adapter
NetworkInterface selectedInterface = nets.get(interfaceIndex);
```

Note that you will have to do the "real" conversion of the rest of the program; that is writing a PCap solution in Java, or writing a JNI (Java) interface to call the PCap library routines.

Comment: Thank you for giving me something to work with.  I dont expect the work to be done for me just need help and pointer on where to go with all the information that is available.  Thanks again.

Comment: @PGFDBUG, well, I don't typically do all of the work for someone; however, the parts you had issue with were not really PCap parts.  Java handles lists differently, and you probably have more to gain by converting C lists to Java Lists than by simulation the C Lists exactly.

Answer (score 0):

WinPcap will always require native coding. You could use JNI to get some of that code (e.g. the select interface part) to java, but you'll never be able to fully convert it. (You can't directly call native dll's from java)

I can't really give you examples on JNI, but there is enough out there to find when searching JNI and Tutorial or the like :).

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have pointers, so a construct like "d->next" won't map 1:1 in Java.

You'll have to figure out how to create a Java object that corresponds to whatever your "d" is.  The rest looks like simple iteration and calls to System.out.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by ***conversion***?
Are you trying to write an equivalent C program to Java?Is it an existing project or you wrote a program in C first and now you want to write the same program in Java?
In any case you should get a good grip with both languages because they differ in the way you write programs that is C is a imperative/procedural language whereas Java is an object-oriented one. This alone means programming 'style' varies differently due to language semantics (and programming patterns, while language-agnostic, are applied differently too).

P.S.: I assume you are a beginner which, if I am correct, does not justify your votes down.

Comment: Thank you I am a beginner I have a decent grasp of c and am trying to understand Java.  Some of the things I dont process well yet that is all.